# Can someone tell me how to fix this php xampp error in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, xampp

I don't know why I'm getting this problem help please I have my code an entire program it just doesn't connect to my Xampp Server

[image]

All i am trying is to connect it to my xampp server

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, it was the space between words